# How do I limit the number of rows in a table while designing a rdlc report?

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am new to windows desktop application development.
I am designing a report in an rdlc file in which I am using a table to display the items. The table expands automatically as per the number of records.

I want to limit the display to a maximum of 10 record in that table. How do I achieve this?

Comment: you mean to say there should be just 10 records displayed? Ot do u mean there can be more records but you just want to display 10 records at a  time.

Comment: Yes Sir, I want to display maximum of 10 records. If there are less than 10 then all records should be displayed other wise 10 if there exist more than 10. @Praveen Nambiar

Comment: check my answer and see if it works out for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You will have to follow few steps:

Step 1: Right Click on your Table(that is next to First Column, Second Row) and Select Add Group
Step 2: Under Add Group - Select Parent Group
Step 3: There you need to click on `fx` and add this - =Ceiling(Rownumber(nothing)/10).
Step 4: Click Ok and right click the group just created. Give a name to it.
Step 5: Select 2nd option PageBreaks and check 'Between each instance of group'
Step 6: Click on Sorting and Delete exisiting sorting. Thats it.
Step 7: Delete the new Grouping Column.

> I have attached image for Step 1:

[image]

Comment: I followed the suggested steps but I am getting the error.
`A sort expression for the tablix 'Tablix1' uses the function RowNumber.RowNumber cannot be used in sort expressions.` @Praveen Nambiar

Comment: Sir I did the same but not displaying the 10 records exactly. It displays the number of records as in database. @Praveen Nambiar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25844/discussion-between-praveen-nambiar-and-riyaz-kalva)

Comment: First it gave the error of sort expression then I removed the sorting but now I am getting 11 records instead 10.