# Display only 10 records per page in RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have followed all instructions given on below link:
***[How do I limit the number of rows in a table while designing a rdlc report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292703/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-while-designing-a-rdlc-report)***

But it display only one record per page.Can anybody help to come out of this.

Comment: [**May be related**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a1fc1c3-bef6-4b0e-bfef-5d150088eb2a/report-change-the-number-of-rows-per-page?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/11/displaying-fixed-number-of-rows-per-ssrs-report-page.html

i have used this and it is working as expected.
are you using RDLC report viewer in standalone mode or you are using report viewer with report server integrated mode?